# Copy data to next empty column and create data header

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I need to copy data from a daily order form to another sheet in the next empty column. To complicate the problem, the data needs to have a date as it's header taken from another cell.

The sheet with data to copy is called Order1
The sheet to paste into is called OrderHistory

The data range to copy is H7:37 - this needs to go into the OrderHistory in the next available column. The first would be C5:C35.

The date header is in sheet Order1 in cell L2.
That would need to be pasted into cell above the new column of data pasted from above. So in the first instance C4.

This process would be repeated daily.

I used the macro record function to copy the data:

```vb
Sub RecordData()
'
' RecordData Macro
' Copy daily order data to maintain history.
'

'
    Sheets("Order1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
    Range("H7").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
    Range("H7:H37").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("OrderHistory").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Order1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
    Range("L2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("OrderHistory").Select
    Range("C4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

This doesn't find the next free column, and doesn't seem to copy the date either.

Comment: Yes this is possible in VBA. Have you begun writing it, for example using the macro recorder as a starting point?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've not started as I wasn't sure how to make sure the next blank column was used, but I can record up to that point.

Comment: It need formatting regarding SO guidelines

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Order1")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("OrderHistory")

copySheet.Range("L2").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

copySheet.Range("H7:H50").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Ta